# How can I assign unique value to each duplicate value in a column in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have data in my table as below

[image: Table having duplicate data]

Now I want to generate unique rank value to each duplicate value like 1,2,3,4 etc as below

[image: Table with unique rank value]

How to do this in SQL Server 2016?

Comment: Rank cannot be unique for duplicates... you just need to number them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be looking for `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by id, name order by deptid) as ranking
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DENSE_RANK as well,

```
select table.*,
   DENSE_RANK() over (order by id, name ,deptid) as RANK
from table;
```